# Single to multiple Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

In my foreach loop, I'm fetching data from csv file, after rendering it in the array, the data is rendered collectively, but I want it to show column wise as in csv file or I have shown in the below second code example:

```
Array(
[0] => op1
[1] => op2
[2] => ans 1
[3] => op4
[4] => op1
[5] => op2
[6] => ans 2
[7] => op4
[8] => op1
[9] => op2
[10] => ans 3
[11] => op4
[12] => op1
[13] => op2
[14] => ans 4
[15] => op4
[16] => op1
[17] => op2
[18] => ans 5
[19] => op4
[20] => op1
)
```

I want to this

```
Array
(
    option[0]=>
        Array(
        [0] => op1
        [1] => op2
        [2] => ans 1
        [3] => op4
        )

    option[1]=>
        Array(
        [0] => op1
        [1] => op2
        [2] => ans 2
        [3] => op4
        )
    option[2]=>
        Array(
        [0] => op1
        [1] => op2
        [2] => ans 2
        [3] => op4
        )   
    option[3]=>
        Array(
        [0] => op1
        [1] => op2
        [2] => ans 2
        [3] => op4
        )           
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use array_chuck() function like this:

```
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your existing `foreach` loop use **Modulus** for divide array in groups.

```
$final_arr= array();
$new_key = 0;
foreach($csv_data as $key => $value){
    $new_key = $new_key;
    if($key % 4 == 0){
        $new_key += 1;
    }
$final_arr[$new_key][]= $value;
}
```

Here I assume you got your csv data in `$csv_data` this variable.

Hope it helps to you.

Answer (score 0):

From [str_getcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)'s manual page, first two comments:

> That does not produce the desired results, if fields contain
>   linebreaks.
>
> Handy one liner to parse a CSV file into an array:

```php
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));
```

> This will create an array of associative arrays with the first row
>   column headers as the keys.

```php
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file));
array_walk($csv, function(&$a) use ($csv) {
    $a = array_combine($csv[0], $a);
});
array_shift($csv); // remove column header
```